# Question on the arrangement of spacing in the newlfm document class

Tags: letters, newlfm

I'd like to reduce the space between the address part `\addrfrom` and the greeting text `\greetto` in  the `newlfm` document class. For instance, when I compile my file;

```
\documentclass[11pt,stdletter,dateno,sigleft]{newlfm} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\addrfrom{
\today\\[11pt] 
\textbf{Dudley Dursley}\\
4 Privet Drive, Little Whinging, Surrey\\
 England, Great Britain
}
\greetto{Dear Dr. Snape,} 

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}


\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

there is a considerably big gap between two fields. I tried `\vspace`, but did not work. I was wondering if someone could help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This length is set using `\addrfromskipafter{<len>}`. So, add something like this to your preamble:

```
\addrfromskipafter{10pt}% Default is 36pt
```

---

There's no need for using [`newlfm`](//ctan.org/pkg/newlfm). Instead, the `article` class is sufficient:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\hspace{.6\linewidth}%
\begin{tabular}{ l }
  \today                                  \\[11pt]
  \bfseries Dudley Dursley                \\
  4 Privet Drive, Little Whinging, Surrey \\
  England, Great Britain
\end{tabular}  

\bigskip

Dear Dr.~Snape,

\medskip

Your letter here.

\end{document}
```

It allows you much more freedom to manage the spacing and placement of content.